# Fixed background with scrollable content of the elements in front

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a responsive Website. With quite an effort (and help from the community) I managed to mount a fixed background image. But now I am encountering two issues:

1. With small screens, the content of the elements in front of the image is cut off at the bottom, scrolling is not possible.
2. The footer is overlapping the other elements.

html/ css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the Homepage</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <style type="text/css">
            html {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                font-size: 62.5%;
            }

            Body {
                font-size: 1.6px; 
                font-size: 1.6rem; 
                line-height: 1.5;
                font-family: "Courier New", Courier, sans-serif;
                color: black;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction:column;
            }

            #backgroundImage {
                height: auto;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            #backgroundImage::before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                background-image: url('ImageLake.bmp');
                background-size: cover;
                opacity: 0.1;
            }

            #Page {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                width: 95%; 
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                margin: 0.3em auto;
                border: 0.3em solid #00ccff;
                border-radius: 5em;
            }

            #Logo {
                font-size: 3.5rem;
                font-weight: 650;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 0.5em;
                letter-spacing: 0.2em;
            }

            #Center {
                height: auto;
            }

            footer {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
            }

            /* -- STYLES FOR NAVIGATION-MENU -- */

            ul#navMain {
                list-style-type: none; 
            }

            li.menu-eintrag a:link,
            li.menu-eintrag a:visited,
            li.menu-eintrag a:hover,
            li.menu-eintrag a:focus,
            li.menu-eintrag a:active {
                font-size: 120%;
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;   
            }

            li.menu-eintrag a:hover {
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .terminvereinbarung a:link,
            .terminvereinbarung a:visited,
            .terminvereinbarung a:focus,
            .terminvereinbarung a:active {
                font-size: 120%;
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none; 
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: 0.5em;
                border: 0.5em solid rgba(0,204,255,0.4);
                border-radius: 5em;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            .terminvereinbarung a:hover {
                border: 0.5em dotted rgba(50,204,255,1);
                border-radius: 5em;
            }

            .menu-eintrag a:link,
            .menu-eintrag a:visited,
            .menu-eintrag a:focus,
            .menu-eintrag a:active {
                font-size: 120%;
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none; 
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: 0.5em;
                border: 0.5em solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
                border-radius: 5em;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            .menu-eintrag a:hover {
                border: 0.5em solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
                border-radius: 5em;
            }

            @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
                #nav {
                    display: table;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }

                #nav li {
                    font-size: 80%;
                    width: auto;
                    display: inline;
                    white-space: nowrap;
                }

                #Center {
                    display: inline-block; 
                    padding: 0 1em; 
                }

                #begruessung {
                    text-align: center;
                }

                #ColumnRight {
                    padding: 1em;
                }
            }

            @media screen and (min-width: 64em){
                header {
                    padding-top: 0em;
                }

                #Content {  
                    display: flex;
                }

                #nav,
                #ColumnRight {
                    width: 20%;
                    float: left;
                }

                #nav li {
                    display: block;
                    font-size: 100%;
                    width: 100%;
                    float: none;
                    padding: 1em;
                }   

                #Center {
                    float: left;
                    padding: 0em 3em;
                    width: 50%;
                }

                #begruessung {
                    text-align: left;
                }

                li.menu-eintrag a:link,
                li.menu-eintrag a:visited,
                li.menu-eintrag a:hover,
                li.menu-eintrag a:focus,
                li.menu-eintrag a:active {
                }

                #ColumnRight a:link,
                #ColumnRight a:visited,
                #ColumnRight a:hover,
                #ColumnRight a:focus,
                #ColumnRight a:active {   
                }
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="backgroundImage">
            <div id="Page">

                <header>
                    <div id="Logo">
                        Header of the Page
                    </div>
                </header>

                <div id ="Content">
                    <nav id="nav">
                        <ul id="navMain">
                            <li class="terminvereinbarung"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">Alpha</a>
                            <li class="menu-eintrag"><a href="index.html" class="active">Beta</a>
                            <li class="menu-eintrag"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">Gamma</a>
                            <li class="menu-eintrag"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">Delta</a>
                            <li class="menu-eintrag"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">Epsilon</a>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>

                    <div id="Center">
                        <h1 id="begruessung">
                            Welcome at our place! </h1>
                        <h2>
                            We are opening soon.
                        </h2>
                        <h3>
                            We are hiring.
                        </h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci. Aenean nec lorem. In porttitor. Donec laoreet nonummy augue. Suspendisse dui purus, scelerisque at, vulputate vitae, pretium mattis, nunc. Mauris eget neque at sem venenatis eleifend. Ut nonummy. Fusce aliquet pede non pede. Suspendisse dapibus lorem pellentesque magna. Integer nulla. Donec blandit feugiat ligula. Donec hendrerit, felis et imperdiet euismod, purus ipsum pretium metus, in lacinia nulla nisl eget sapien. Donec ut est in lectus consequat consequat.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <aside id="ColumnRight">
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis gestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci. Aenean nec lorem. In porttitor. Donec laoreet nonummy augue.
                    </aside>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <ul id="footerList" >
                <li class="footer-menu-eintrag"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">&copy; 2021 Mister Me</a>
                <li class="footer-menu-eintrag"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">Contact</a>
                <li class="footer-menu-eintrag"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">Alpha</a>
                <li class="footer-menu-eintrag"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">Beta</a>
            </ul>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

How can I make the content of the elements in the foreground scrollable?
How can I move the footer to the bottom without it overlapping the other elements?

Comment: Can you share a sandbox for this?

Comment: No, I am sorry, I have no experience with sandboxes. But I think I found a viable solution (with some little drawbacks) at least for the scrolling-issue: In the css-style for #Page three lines should be added: ```height: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;```

Comment: Still, the problem of the footer which overlaps the other elements remains to be solved.

Comment: I mean like this one https://codesandbox.io/ or codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. to avoid cut off of content at the bottom change #page position fixed to relative.

   #page{
   position: relative;
   }

then a scrollbar will appear.
2. to avoid overlapping of footer use:

```
   footer{
       position:relative;
       bottom:0;
}
```

and to be honest your styling practice is not good. You should use class to style elements instead of ids.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works!! And yes: I know my style is bad, I will take your advise to the heart!

Answer (score 1):

There were actually quite a few tweaks that I think should be made to get you what you wanted.

Firstly, the background. I would go with `position: fixed;` rather than `position: absolute;` to make sure the background is completely independent of the content.

Secondly, the footer does not need the `position` attribute set, rather you could make it part of the flexbox layout, setting the `flex` attribute on your **#backgroundImage** element (and removing the `position` attribute from **backgroundImage**).

Lastly, make sure the **html** and **body** tags have a full height set in the CSS so everything will scale on larger screens.

You end up with something like:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.6px; 
  font-size: 1.6rem; 
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#backgroundImage {
  height: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#backgroundImage::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Pleiades_large.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

#Page {
  width: 95%; 
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0.3em auto;
  border: 0.3em solid #00ccff;
  border-radius: 5em;
}

#Logo {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: 650;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

#Center {
  height: auto;
}

footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

/* -- STYLES FOR NAVIGATION-MENU -- */

ul#navMain {
  list-style-type: none; 
}

li.menu-eintrag a:link,
li.menu-eintrag a:visited,
li.menu-eintrag a:hover,
li.menu-eintrag a:focus,
li.menu-eintrag a:active {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;   
}

li.menu-eintrag a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.terminvereinbarung a:link,
.terminvereinbarung a:visited,
.terminvereinbarung a:focus,
.terminvereinbarung a:active {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 0.5em solid rgba(0,204,255,0.4);
  border-radius: 5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.terminvereinbarung a:hover {
  border: 0.5em dotted rgba(50,204,255,1);
  border-radius: 5em;
}

.menu-eintrag a:link,
.menu-eintrag a:visited,
.menu-eintrag a:focus,
.menu-eintrag a:active {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 0.5em solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-radius: 5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu-eintrag a:hover {
  border: 0.5em solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  border-radius: 5em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  #nav {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  #nav li {
    font-size: 80%;
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  #Center {
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 0 1em; 
  }

  #begruessung {
    text-align: center;
  }

  #ColumnRight {
    padding: 1em;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 64em){
  header {
    padding-top: 0em;
  }

  #Content {  
    display: flex;
  }

  #nav,
  #ColumnRight {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
  }

  #nav li {
    display: block;
    font-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    padding: 1em;
  }   

  #Center {
    float: left;
    padding: 0em 3em;
    width: 50%;
  }

  #begruessung {
    text-align: left;
  }

  li.menu-eintrag a:link,
  li.menu-eintrag a:visited,
  li.menu-eintrag a:hover,
  li.menu-eintrag a:focus,
  li.menu-eintrag a:active {
  }

  #ColumnRight a:link,
  #ColumnRight a:visited,
  #ColumnRight a:hover,
  #ColumnRight a:focus,
  #ColumnRight a:active {   
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="backgroundImage">
  <div id="Page">

    <header>
      <div id="Logo">
        Header of the Page
      </div>
    </header>

    <div id ="Content">
      <nav id="nav">
        <ul id="navMain">
          <li class="terminvereinbarung"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">Alpha</a>
          <li class="menu-eintrag"><a href="index.html" class="active">Beta</a>
          <li class="menu-eintrag"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">Gamma</a>
          <li class="menu-eintrag"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">Delta</a>
          <li class="menu-eintrag"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">Epsilon</a>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div id="Center">
        <h1 id="begruessung">
          Welcome at our place! </h1>
        <h2>
          We are opening soon.
        </h2>
        <h3>
          We are hiring.
        </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci. Aenean nec lorem. In porttitor. Donec laoreet nonummy augue. Suspendisse dui purus, scelerisque at, vulputate vitae, pretium mattis, nunc. Mauris eget neque at sem venenatis eleifend. Ut nonummy. Fusce aliquet pede non pede. Suspendisse dapibus lorem pellentesque magna. Integer nulla. Donec blandit feugiat ligula. Donec hendrerit, felis et imperdiet euismod, purus ipsum pretium metus, in lacinia nulla nisl eget sapien. Donec ut est in lectus consequat consequat.
        </p>
        <h3>
          We are hiring.
        </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci. Aenean nec lorem. In porttitor. Donec laoreet nonummy augue. Suspendisse dui purus, scelerisque at, vulputate vitae, pretium mattis, nunc. Mauris eget neque at sem venenatis eleifend. Ut nonummy. Fusce aliquet pede non pede. Suspendisse dapibus lorem pellentesque magna. Integer nulla. Donec blandit feugiat ligula. Donec hendrerit, felis et imperdiet euismod, purus ipsum pretium metus, in lacinia nulla nisl eget sapien. Donec ut est in lectus consequat consequat.
        </p>
        <h3>
          We are hiring.
        </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci. Aenean nec lorem. In porttitor. Donec laoreet nonummy augue. Suspendisse dui purus, scelerisque at, vulputate vitae, pretium mattis, nunc. Mauris eget neque at sem venenatis eleifend. Ut nonummy. Fusce aliquet pede non pede. Suspendisse dapibus lorem pellentesque magna. Integer nulla. Donec blandit feugiat ligula. Donec hendrerit, felis et imperdiet euismod, purus ipsum pretium metus, in lacinia nulla nisl eget sapien. Donec ut est in lectus consequat consequat.
        </p>
        <h3>
          We are hiring.
        </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci. Aenean nec lorem. In porttitor. Donec laoreet nonummy augue. Suspendisse dui purus, scelerisque at, vulputate vitae, pretium mattis, nunc. Mauris eget neque at sem venenatis eleifend. Ut nonummy. Fusce aliquet pede non pede. Suspendisse dapibus lorem pellentesque magna. Integer nulla. Donec blandit feugiat ligula. Donec hendrerit, felis et imperdiet euismod, purus ipsum pretium metus, in lacinia nulla nisl eget sapien. Donec ut est in lectus consequat consequat.
        </p>
        <h3>
          We are hiring.
        </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci. Aenean nec lorem. In porttitor. Donec laoreet nonummy augue. Suspendisse dui purus, scelerisque at, vulputate vitae, pretium mattis, nunc. Mauris eget neque at sem venenatis eleifend. Ut nonummy. Fusce aliquet pede non pede. Suspendisse dapibus lorem pellentesque magna. Integer nulla. Donec blandit feugiat ligula. Donec hendrerit, felis et imperdiet euismod, purus ipsum pretium metus, in lacinia nulla nisl eget sapien. Donec ut est in lectus consequat consequat.
        </p>
        <h3>
          We are hiring.
        </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci. Aenean nec lorem. In porttitor. Donec laoreet nonummy augue. Suspendisse dui purus, scelerisque at, vulputate vitae, pretium mattis, nunc. Mauris eget neque at sem venenatis eleifend. Ut nonummy. Fusce aliquet pede non pede. Suspendisse dapibus lorem pellentesque magna. Integer nulla. Donec blandit feugiat ligula. Donec hendrerit, felis et imperdiet euismod, purus ipsum pretium metus, in lacinia nulla nisl eget sapien. Donec ut est in lectus consequat consequat.
        </p>
      </div>

      <aside id="ColumnRight">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis gestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci. Aenean nec lorem. In porttitor. Donec laoreet nonummy augue.
      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <ul id="footerList" >
    <li class="footer-menu-eintrag"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">&copy; 2021 Mister Me</a>
    <li class="footer-menu-eintrag"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">Contact</a>
    <li class="footer-menu-eintrag"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">Alpha</a>
    <li class="footer-menu-eintrag"><a href="#DUMMY_LINK">Beta</a>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The scrolling does work now and the footer is fixed. But when I put more text into #Center then this text still gets overlapped by the footer.

Comment: @curbholes I am not able to reproduce that problem. I edited my post to include more text in the `#Center` element but it still works just fine for me. Without seeing what text was added (or how it was added), it's hard to say why you are seeing the footer overlap text.

Comment: Yes, it is working, you are right I did not insert your code correctly. Thank you!